# Query for Lightswitch in GraphQL

Tags: craft-pro, graphql

I have two entry types that I want to show in a sorted list (by postDate, with paginating).

```
{
  entries(
    type: ["entryType1", "entryType2"],
    orderBy: "postDate desc",
    limit: 5,
    offset: 0
  ) {
    id
    title
    postDate
    typeHandle
  }
}
```

This already works. Now the second post type `entryType2` should have an optional Lightswitch `showInList`, where the editor can decide if the entry should appear in the list.

```
{
  entries(
    type: ["entryType1", "entryType2"],
    orderBy: "postDate desc",
    showInList: 1,
    limit: 5,
    offset: 0
  ) {
    id
    title
    postDate
    typeHandle
  }
}
```

Unfortunately with the adapted querying I only get the entries of the type with the Lightswitch field declared. When setting `showInList: null` I get all entries of both entry types, but its ignoring if `showInList` is true/false for any entry of the second post type.
I tested different QueryArguments but its seems they all have no effect.

Every QueryArgument is handled as if `true`

Tested:

- `showInList: 1` → shows only entries of `entryType2` with
  showInList set to `true`, ignores `entryType2`
- `showInList: ['not 1']` → I thought this would give all entries of `entryType2` with `showInList` set to false but it behaves the same as `showInList: 1`
- `showInList: null` → shows entries of both types but ignores the `showInList` field

is there something like `showInList: ['1 or undefined']` or any other `QueryArgument` that would give me the expected result?

Tested in CraftCMS 3.4.17.1 with full schema

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just saw this resolved issue on GitHub: https://github.com/craftcms/cms/issues/5930

So Lightswitch querying should be fixed in the upcoming release CraftCMS 3.5

---

Edit: there is a workaround until 3.5 is released. see comment by @harrymee123 and my example query at https://github.com/craftcms/cms/issues/5930#issuecomment-657417173